# What is the replacement for -n switch in Aptitude in 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, aptitude

I am trying to purge XFCE from my PC (it got fubared so I want to destroy it and reinstall it). I noticed aptitude doesn't have the `-n` wildcard any more.

So `aptitude purge -nxfce4` just lists the help.

What is the replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never heard of such option, I suppose you are thinkin of the `~n` search term ([Search Term Reference](http://www.algebraicthunk.net/~dburrows/projects/aptitude/doc/en/ch02s03s05.html)), used as

```
aptitude purge ~nxfce4
```

or equivalently

```
aptitude purge '?name(xfce4)'
```

Comment: Exactly. Didn't know about the other notation. If I do `aptitude purge -nxfce` I get the following: `aptitude: invalid option -- 'n'`

and the list of options. Your second notation works tho.